# Absolute Positioning Not Expanding

Tags: css, html, position, css-position

I have the following code:

```
<div id="display_vendors">
<ul class="vendor_types">
<li>Category 1</li>                         
</ul>
</div>
<div id="display_vendors_container">
<h4>Search Results</h4><br>Here are your search results! You can simply navigate to the other categories by clicking on one on the left hand side:<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>Testing<br><br><br><br><br>More<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>Sljf
</div>
```

Then I have the following CSS:

```
#display_vendors ul.vendor_types li {
background-color:#000000;
color:#FFFFFF;
width:200px;
line-height:1.5em;
margin:2px 0 0 0;
padding:10px;
border-width:1px;
border-color:#000000;
border-style:solid;
-webkit-border-top-left-radius: 10px;
-webkit-border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
-moz-border-radius-topleft: 10px;
-moz-border-radius-bottomleft: 10px;
border-top-left-radius: 10px;
border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
display:block;
height:100%;
}

#display_vendors ul.vendor_types li:hover {
background-color:#949494;
}

#display_vendors_container{
position:absolute;
top:59px;
left:221px;
width:700px;
height:100%;
border-width:1px;
border-color:#000000;
border-style:solid;
-webkit-border-radius: 10px;
-webkit-border-top-left-radius: 0;
-moz-border-radius: 10px;
-moz-border-radius-topleft: 0;
border-radius: 10px;
border-top-left-radius: 0;
padding:10px;
min-height:400px;
}

.dispay_vendor_type {
color:#FFFFFF;
text-decoration:underline;
}

.dispay_vendor_type:hover {
color:#FFFFFF;
text-decoration:underline;
}
```

Now my issue is that the #display_vendors_container won't display the whole content of the div. It will only make it the same height as the #display_vendors div. If I remove the absolute positioning on the #display_vendors_container it displays all the content but not in the right place. Any ideas on what could be causing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The height: 100%; in #display_vendors_container is your problem; delete it and it will be fine.

Proof: http://jsfiddle.net/w3LSV/

Comment: In your example though, the border doesn't get all of the content. There is still content outside of the border then.

Comment: Really? It doesn't look that way to me; which browser are you using?

Comment: I found an issue. There is other code that has it in a wrapper. The wrapper doesn't recognize how big the div is. The overflow of the wrapper is set to hidden so that is why it isn't displaying. Not sure what to change though.

Comment: Put it in a JSFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/ and I'll take a look (remember to save it).

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/a66sJ/ - This should be everything you need to play around with it.

Comment: Interesting; I can still see nothing wrong with it at all; are you sure that's everything?

Comment: Yes that's all. On mine, it is displayed below the vendor 1 and 2. I want the top of that to be aligned with those. There can be more or less vendor tabs depending on user input. I tried to make the top be negative but that would only work if those were static. I always want it to line up to the top of the vendor 1 tab.

Comment: Oh OK. I'll see what I can do about that.

Comment: Yes, that looks more like the desired results. What did you change?

Answer (score 0):

In your CSS add:

```
body, html {height:100%}
```